# This SQL to LINQ

Tags: .net, linq

How would you convert this SQL statement to LINQ, most efficient ?

```
SELECT categoryName, 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt 
         FROM itemCategories 
        WHERE (categories.categoryId = itemCategories.categoryId) 
          AND (Items.countryPartId = 1)) AS cnt 
  FROM categories, Items
```

This is the LINQ query I've got right now:

```
var q =
    from c in context.categories 
    select new CategoryCount
    {
        CategoryName = c.categoryName, 
        Counter = (
            from i in context.itemCategories 
            where c.categoryId == i.categoryId 
            select i).Count()
    };
```

Comment: this is the LINQ clause without the AND in the WHERE clause:

var q = (from c in context.categories
 select new CategoryCount
 {
   CategoryName = c.categoryName,
            Counter = (from i in context.itemCategories where c.categoryId == i.categoryId select i).Count()
});

Comment: We're not here to write your program, show us what you've come up with already and we'll be happy to improve it.

Comment: And what is it your SQL query is supposed to do. I see you're doing a cross join over `categories` and `items`. This will get you every `categoryName` N times where N is the number of items. Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should produce the exact same query (excluding the seemingly unnecessary use of the `Items` table) and is much more natural to me IMHO.

```
var query = from c in context.categories 
            join ic in context.itemCategories
                on c.categoryId equals ic.categoryId into joined
            select new CategoryCount
            {
                CategoryName = c.categoryName,
                Counter = joined.Count(),
            };
```

If the join makes you queasy for whatever reason, here's an alternative.

```
var query = from c in context.categories 
            select new CategoryCount
            {
                CategoryName = c.categoryName,
                Counter = context.itemCategories
                                 .Where(ic => ic.categoryId == c.categoryId)
                                 .Count(),
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried myself. So sorry for the inconvience Steven, it won't happen again :)

```
var q = (from c in context.categories
        from it in context.Items
        select new CategoryCount
        {
            CategoryName = c.categoryName,
            Counter = (from i in context.itemCategories
                    where c.categoryId == i.categoryId && it.countryPartId == 1 select i).Count()
        });
```